# Exim unable to open file for reading

Tags: centos7, exim

I am working on getting an email server to send email from php

Centos 7

php 7.2

Exim version 4.92

Opendkim

If i change this line in my exim.conf file it will change the error so I know the error is coming from there

```
dkim_private_key = /etc/opendkim/keys/domain.com/default.private
```

The error:

```
2019-08-24 00:01:33 1i1NF6-000241-Vr unable to open file for reading: /etc/opendkim/keys/domain.com/default.private
```

Permissions:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 opendkim opendkim 887 Aug 23 22:48 /etc/opendkim/keys/domain.com/default.private
```

I have changed the ownership to exim:exim

Changed the permission to 777

Restarted exim and opendkim after each change

Nothing seem to help

```
[root@mail ~]# ll -d /etc/
drwxr-xr-x. 86 root root 8192 Aug 24 00:06 /etc/
[root@mail ~]# ll -d /etc/opendkim/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root opendkim 107 Aug 23 22:51 /etc/opendkim
[root@mail ~]# ll -d /etc/opendkim/keys/
drwxr-x--- 3 opendkim opendkim 29 Aug 23 22:48 /etc/opendkim/keys/
[root@mail ~]# ll -d /etc/opendkim/keys/example.com/
drwxr-xr-x 2 opendkim opendkim 63 Aug 23 22:49 /etc/opendkim/keys/example.com/
[root@mail ~]# ll /etc/opendkim/keys/example.com/
-rw-r--r-- 1 opendkim opendkim 887 Aug 23 22:48 default.private
-rw-r--r-- 1 opendkim opendkim 319 Aug 23 22:48 default.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exim reads the key only when it is needed. This means that all keys and certificates must be available for the non-root user exim runs as (which is `exim` on Red Hat derivative systems if memory serves).

Since the `/etc/opendkim/keys/` directory is executable only for `opendkim` and its group, the exim process won't be able to enter to that directory, so it won't be able to read the key.

Making the `/etc/opendkim/keys` directory accessible to the `exim` user will probably help (add the `exim` user to the `opendkim` group for example).

Comment: That worked, I also had to change the permission to 744, 644 did not work. chown -R exim:exim /etc/opendkim/keys, chmod 744 /etc/opendkim/keys

Comment: That is because the execute bit on directories allows you to change to that directory, the read flag in itself is not enough (in fact, it is not even needed in this case, since the exim process won't list directory contents).